# Using ionic ToastController outside a vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to use the ToastController of Ionic outside an vue instance; i've build an separated actions file which will be loaded inside the vue instance itself which handles a request. During this request it does some validations and i would like to throw a toast while something happened. In the vue instance i could do this.$ionic.toastController.create() which is working fine but in this other file there is no vue instance available so i'd tried to import the ToastController there but am not able to make this work.

Someone who can point me in the right direction with this?

I've already tried few options and searching the internet for this; since ionic 4 with vue.js is still in alpha there is very low support at the moment. I'd also use the @modus/ionic-vue instance which is working better then the original from ionic itself at the moment

The actual code will be called during a this.$store.dispatch(RESERVATION_REQUEST) call see example:

```
import { ToastController } from '@modus/ionic-vue'
import axios from 'axios'

const state = {
    status: '',
    classes: {},
}

const getters = {
    //
}

const actions = {
    [RESERVATION_REQUEST]: ({ commit, dispatch }, data) => {
        return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
            axios({ url: 'reservation/create', data: { lesson: data.lesson, date: data.date, team: data.team }, method: 'POST' })
                .then(response => {
                    ToastController.create({
                        duration: 2000,
                        header: 'Confirmation',
                        message: 'Success',
                        position: 'top',
                        showCloseButton: true,
                        closeButtonText: 'Ok',
                    }).then(toast => toast.present());
                    resolve(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    ToastController.create({
                        duration: 2000,
                        header: 'failed',
                        message: error.toString(),
                        position: 'top',
                        showCloseButton: true,
                        closeButtonText: 'Ok',
                    }).then(toast => toast.present());
                    reject(error)
                });
        });
    },
}

const mutations = {
    //
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
}
```

The above code will be called like this:

```
toggleReservation(lesson, date) {
    const team = this.$store.getters.getCurrentId;
    this.$store.dispatch(RESERVATION_REQUEST, { lesson, date, team });
}
```

Would be nice if someone could help me with this; looking for at for a few days right now having the feeling i'm on the right track but can't find the solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do directly then and catch on the $store.dispatch in your vue instance

store:

```
const actions = {
    [RESERVATION_REQUEST]: ({ commit, dispatch }, data) => {
        return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
            axios({ url: 'reservation/create', data: { lesson: data.lesson, date: data.date, team: data.team }, method: 'POST' })
                .then(response => {
                    resolve(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                });
        });
    },
}
```

Vue file:

```
toggleReservation(lesson, date) {
    const team = this.$store.getters.getCurrentId;
    this.$store.dispatch(RESERVATION_REQUEST, { lesson, date, team })
            .then(response => {
                this.$ionic.toastController.create({
                        duration: 2000,
                        header: 'Confirmation',
                        message: 'Success',
                        position: 'top',
                        showCloseButton: true,
                        closeButtonText: 'Ok',
                    }).then(toast => toast.present());
            })
            .catch(error => {
                 this.$ionic.toastController.create({
                        duration: 2000,
                        header: 'failed',
                        message: error.toString(),
                        position: 'top',
                        showCloseButton: true,
                        closeButtonText: 'Ok',
                    }).then(toast => toast.present());
            });

}
```

PS: axios return a promise so if you want you can do return it directly in the store

```
const actions = {
    [RESERVATION_REQUEST]: ({ commit, dispatch }, data) => {
        return axios({ url: 'reservation/create', data: { lesson: data.lesson, date: data.date, team: data.team }, method: 'POST' })
    },
}
```